# How to update offline and online users via Firebase and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a social media project right now. Which I need to have user presence and it is very important. I have seen the methods `onDisconnect()` and then making a user offline, but my main problem is that I am going Firestore for my project.

I want to update the Firestore users.id status to true or false. How can I do this method with `useEffect()` and make online status or offline status?

I want to be willing to update in Firestore `users.id`, not in the realtime database.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way it communicates with its servers, Firestore doesn't have a built-in presence detection system. If you want to integrate a presence system into your Firestore project, you'll have to use the Realtime Database for this as shown in this documentation on [building a presence system in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence).

---

There is a Firebase Extension in development that simplifies this integration down to a few clicks, but that is currently in early access and only available as part of the [Firebase Alpha program](https://firebase.google.com/alpha), and I have no information on when it may become generally available.